# Occasionally on startup, there is no WiFi tab in the settings in Ubuntu 20.04.1 LTS

Tags: networking, dual-boot, wireless

This is on a dual boot machine with Windows, and it seems to always occur when Windows was used last. When I log in, I see that the WiFi isn't connected but when I go to the settings panel, there is no tab for WiFi options, so I'm not exactly sure how to approach this issue. Every time without fail, rebooting solves the problem seamlessly. I've tried scouring the internet for answers but I've only been able to find threads about WiFi not working completely. Of course this is more of an inconvenience than anything, but I'd appreciate any help, thanks!

Comment: Could this be the issue? https://wireless.wiki.kernel.org/en/users/drivers/iwlwifi#about_dual-boot_with_windows_and_fast-boot_enabled  Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Windows doesn't shut down properly by default. Some wireless adapters, e.g. Intel don't work in Ubuntu in this case.

Disable Windows Fast Startup feature.